# how to populate a table with json data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

i'm working on this calculator and when the user select one of the type a little table should appear to select a type from tha table which should be filled with a json data but doesn't work

this my code

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", get_json_data, false);

function get_json_data() {
    var json_url = 'example.json';
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            append_json(data);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", json_url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function append_json(data) {
    var table = document.getElementById('gable');
    data.forEach(function(object) {
        var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
        tbody.innerHTML =
            '<tr>' +
            '<td > <input type="radio" value ="' + object.RendementDuPanneau + '" name="choice" class="rad" /> </td>' +
            '<td>' + object.Fournisseur + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + object.Modele + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + object.PuissanceMaximale + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + object.RendementDuPanneau + '</td>' + '</tr>';
        table.appendChild(tbody);
    });
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

        (elements)[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            const rb = this.querySelector('input[name="choice"]');
            rb.checked = true;

            let selectedValue = rb.value;
            alert(selectedValue);
        });
    }
}
```

json file data look like

```
[{"Fournisseur":"Jinko Solar","Modèle":"JKM270PP-60","PuissanceMaximale":270,"RendementDuPanneau":"16,50%"},{"Fournisseur":"Jinko Solar","Modèle":"JKM275PP-60","PuissanceMaximale":275,"RendementDuPanneau":"16,80%"},{"Fournisseur":"Jinko Solar","Modèle":"JKM280PP-60","PuissanceMaximale":280,"RendementDuPanneau":"17,11%"},{"Fournisseur":"Jinko Solar","Modèle":"JKM285PP-60","PuissanceMaximale":285,"RendementDuPanneau":"17,41%"},{"Fournisseur":"Jinko Solar","Modèle":"JKM320PP-72","PuissanceMaximale":320,"RendementDuPanneau":"16,49%"},{"Fournisseur":"Jinko Solar","Modèle":"JKM325PP-72","PuissanceMaximale":325,"RendementDuPanneau":"16,75%"},{"Fournisseur":"Jinko Solar","Modèle":"JKM330PP-72","PuissanceMaximale":330,"RendementDuPanneau":"17,01%"},{"Fournisseur":"Jinko Solar","Modèle":"JKM335PP-72","PuissanceMaximale":335,"RendementDuPanneau":"17,26%"}]
```

this how it looks [image: result]

this how it should look like [image: like]

Comment: Define and initialize `tbody` outside the `.forEach()` method. Also, put `table.appendChild(tbody);` outside; after the method.

Comment: already did still nothing

Comment: Inside the `append_json()` what is the output of `console.log( data );`?

Comment: the array shows up in the console, i tried to only to show the sepatly and it woks nrml so maybe it from the limited space i'm givin it

Comment: What is the output of `console.log( $('#gable').length )`?

Comment: it's returning 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215007/discussion-between-peterka-and-alchemist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An output of zero from the following indicates there's no element with id `gable`.

```
console.log( $('#gable').length );
```

Please confirm that the table has this id, otherwise add an id attribute, thus:

```
id="gable"
```